# How to switch SSH keys for different identities in github

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have different users for different github organizations, each with their own ssh keys.  How can I easily switch between ssh keys for different accounts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+multiple+accounts

Answer (score 2):

Its quite possible with a little configuration in the ~/.ssh/config file.

The trick is - the `Host` in the .ssh config does not have to be the real `Hostname`

```
# add the ~/.ssh/id_altUsername file for the new user on Github
# ssh -T git@github-altUsername # test it can connect
# git clone git@github-altUsername:alt_username/[repo].git

Host github-altUsername
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_altUsername
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```